# Change Collation in Netezza Server

Tags: collation, netezza

I am trying to sort a list of records in Netezza, but their sort order seems different from SQL server.

In Netezza, I get AZ ahead of Aaaaa.
In SQL Server, I get Aaaaa ahead of AZ.

My SQL server collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS.
My Netezza collation is Latin9 Unicode.

Is there a way to change my Netezza collation to match my SQL server?

Answer (score 1):

To set the session for LATIN1, enter:

```
set nz_encoding=LATIN1
```

[Netezza docs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ntz/v7r0m3/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.nz.dbu.doc%2Fc_dbuser_examples_utf8.html)
[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/multibyte.html)